# Scipy Differential Evolution - init specifying start

Tags: python, scipy, differential-evolution

Problematic code:

```
result = differential_evolution(GA_optimisation, bounds, init=initial_GA_params, args=args)
```

> init : str or array-like, optional
>   Specify which type of population initialization is performed. Should be one of:
>   array specifying the initial population. The array should have shape (M, len(x)), where len(x) is the number of parameters. init is clipped to bounds before use.

I am trying to specifying a known starting point for an optimisation. The shape of my array is (1,99), I get the below ValueError

Error:

```
ValueError("The population supplied needs to have shape (M, len(x)), where M > 4.")
```

I am unsure of what M actually is? and am unable to find it anywhere in the documentation. Could anyone help with explaining this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add a code snippet so it is easier to understand what you are trying to do with the code and what might be going wrong.

Comment: `result = differential_evolution(GA_optimisation, bounds, init=initial_GA_params, args=args)`

Comment: Above is how I call the function, below is the error

Comment: _raise ValueError("The population supplied needs to have shape"
ValueError: The population supplied needs to have shape (M, len(x)), where M > 4.
_

Comment: Please check the guidelines on how to ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to create a good code snippet - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Without these, you are unlikely to get any help.

Answer (score 0):

M is the population size. The default for differential_evolution in SciPy is 15. You need to get the shape (M,99) with M=15, unless specified otherwise.